# as.POSIXct gives an unexpected timezone

Tags: r, zoneinfo, posixct

I'm trying to convert a [yearmon](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=zoo:yearmon) date (from the [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) package) to a POSIXct in the UTC timezone. 
This is what I tried to do:

```
> as.POSIXct(as.yearmon("2010-01-01"), tz="UTC")
[1] "2010-01-01 01:00:00 CET"
```

I get the same when I convert a Date:

```
> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2010-01-01"),tz="UTC")
[1] "2010-01-01 01:00:00 CET"
```

The only way to get it to work is to pass a character as an argument:

```
> as.POSIXct("2010-01-01", tz="UTC")
[1] "2010-01-01 UTC"
```

I looked into the documentation of [DateTimeClasses](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html), [tzset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/tzset.3.html) and [timezones](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/timezones.html). My /etc/localtime is set to Europe/Amsterdam. I couldn't find a way to set the tz to UTC, other than setting the TZ environment variable:

```
> Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
> as.POSIXct(as.Date("2010-01-01"),tz="UTC")
[1] "2010-01-01 UTC"
```

Is it possible to directly set the timezone when creating a POSIXct from a yearmon or Date?

Edit:

I checked the functions as.POSIXct.yearmon. This one passes to the as.POSIXct.Date.

```
> zoo:::as.POSIXct.yearmon
function (x, tz = "", ...) 
as.POSIXct(as.Date(x), tz = tz, ...)
<environment: namespace:zoo>
```

So like Joshua says the timezone gets lost in the as.POSIXct.Date. For now I'll use Richies suggestion to set the tzone by hand using:

attr(x, "tzone") <- 'UTC'

This solves the issue of the lost tzone, which is only used for presentation and not internally like Grothendieck and Dwin suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `as.POSIXct.Date` doesn't pass `...` to `.POSIXct`.

```
> as.POSIXct.Date
function (x, ...) 
.POSIXct(unclass(x) * 86400)
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Answer (score 5):

<strike>You *are* setting the timezone correctly in your code.</strike> The problem you are perceiving is only at the output stage. POSIX values are all referenced to UTC/GMT. Dates are assumed to be midnight times. Midnight UTC *is* 1 AM CET  ( which is apparently where *you* are).

```
> as.POSIXct(as.yearmon("2010-01-01"), tz="UTC")
[1] "2009-12-31 19:00:00 EST"     # R reports the time in my locale's timezone
> dtval <- as.POSIXct(as.yearmon("2010-01-01"), tz="UTC")
> format(dtval, tz="UTC")         # report the date in UTC  note it is the correct date ... there
[1] "2010-01-01"
> format(dtval, tz="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%d ")
[1] "2010-01-01 "                 # use a format string
> format(dtval, tz="UTC", format="%Y-%m-%d %OS3")
[1] "2010-01-01 00.000"           # use decimal time
```

See `?strptime` for many, many other format possibilities.

Comment: `as.POSIXct` is ignoring the timezone because `as.yearmon` doesn't store the time.  Try your first example with `tz="CET`.  It will give the same rsult as if you'd specified `UTC`.  See my answer for more explanation.

Comment: OK. The problem then is that a date value passed to as.POSIXct will always be assumed to be midnight GMT. (And on second reading I see that you were reading the FM for me.) Sorry for being obtuse, again.

Answer (score 3):

In the help page `?as.POSIXct`, for the `tz` argument it says

> A timezone specification to be used
>   for the conversion, *if one is
>   required*.  System-specific (see time
>   zones), but ‘""’ is the current
>   timezone, and ‘"GMT"’ is UTC
>   (Universal Time, Coordinated).

Does `as.POSIXct(as.yearmon("2010-01-01"), tz="GMT")` work for you?

---

After more perusal of the documentation, in the details section we see:

> Dates without times are treated as
>   being at midnight UTC.

So in your example, the `tz` argument is ignored.  If you use `as.POSIXlt` it is easier to see what happens with the timezone.  The following should all give the same answer, with UTC as the timezone.

```
unclass(as.POSIXlt(as.yearmon("2010-01-01")))
unclass(as.POSIXlt(as.yearmon("2010-01-01"), tz = "UTC"))
unclass(as.POSIXlt(as.yearmon("2010-01-01"), tz = "GMT"))
unclass(as.POSIXlt(as.yearmon("2010-01-01"), tz = "CET"))
```

In fact, since you are using `as.yearmon` (which strips the time out) you will never get to set the timezone.  Compare, e.g.,

```
unclass(as.POSIXlt(as.yearmon("2010-01-01 12:00:00"), tz = "CET"))
unclass(as.POSIXlt("2010-01-01 12:00:00", tz = "CET"))
```

Comment: I didn't quite understand what is meant by "if one is required". When I try to convert to GMT I also still get CET `[1] "2010-01-01 01:00:00 CET"`.

Comment: Actually, the `unclass(as.POSIXlt(x))` is maybe a little over the top.  `attr(x, "tzone")` will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an oddity with the date/time `"POSIXct"` class methods. Try formatting the `"Date"` or `"yearmon"` variable first so that `as.POSIXct.character` rather than `as.POSIXct.{Date, yearmon}` is dispatched:

**Date**

```
> d <- as.Date("2010-01-01")
> as.POSIXct(format(d), tz = "UTC")
[1] "2010-01-01 UTC"
```

**yearmon**

```
> library(zoo)
> y <- as.yearmon("2010-01")
> as.POSIXct(format(y, format = "%Y-%m-01"), tz = "UTC")
[1] "2010-01-01 UTC"
> # or
> as.POSIXct(format(as.Date(y)), tz = "UTC")
[1] "2010-01-01 UTC"
```